# Using Variables in Nested query for Execute Immediate

Tags: sql

This might be a simple query for most of you.

I would like to use a variable in nested query while writing an execute immediate, but somehow it throws an error everytime on the variable in nested query.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE p_decrement_id(
    in_table         VARCHAR2,
    in_seg_nme VARCHAR2)
AS
  version      VARCHAR2(5) := 'v1.0';
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '|| in_table || '
SET X_VERSION_ID  =  X_VERSION_ID   - 1
where DATE_1 = (SELECT DATE_2 FROM CYCLE_DATES
                WHERE SEG_NME = ' ||in_seg_nme||')';

  COMMIT;
END p_decrement_id;
```

for execution I use:

```
set serveroutput on
call p_decrement_id('TEST_DECREMENT', 'TEST');
```

Also, I need to put a constant value within the query
i.e.

```
SELECT DATE_2 FROM CYCLE_DATES
WHERE SEG_NME = ' ||in_seg_nme||'
and indicator = 'Y'
```

Please guide.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use USING to bind params to your query

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '|| in_table || '
SET X_VERSION_ID  =  X_VERSION_ID   - 1
where DATE_1 = (SELECT DATE_2 FROM CYCLE_DATES
                WHERE SEG_NME = :1 and indicator = ''Y'')' using in_seg_nme;
```

Without USING you may try this (as it's VARCHAR2 you need '):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '|| in_table || '
SET X_VERSION_ID  =  X_VERSION_ID   - 1
where DATE_1 = (SELECT DATE_2 FROM CYCLE_DATES
                WHERE SEG_NME = ''' ||in_seg_nme||''' and indicator = ''Y'')';
```

(Two consequent apostrophies is an escape sequence for apostrophe)

Comment: Thank you so much Multisync. It works like a charm. Appreciate your help and to guide me to where I was going wrong.